# Spinner dropdown height first time

Tags: android, kotlin, adapter, android-spinner

I used spinner to make a dropdown of the country flags.
But the dropdown height is not right at the first time as the images show, but it correct itself when I start scrolling in the dropdown or close it and open it again.

[image: Before pressing]

[image: First time]

[image: Second time]

I used custom adapter for the spinner

```
class CustomAdapter(context: AppCompatActivity, resouceId: Int, val list: List<DirectoryResponse>) : ArrayAdapter<DirectoryResponse>(context, resouceId, list) {

    private var inflater: LayoutInflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        //TODO : Recycle the view
        val rowItem = getItem(position)

        val rowview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.flag_spinner, parent, false)

        val imageView = rowview.findViewById(R.id.flag_image) as ImageView
        val padding = dpToPx(6).toInt()
        imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding)

        val imageSize = dpToPx(36).toInt()
        GlideApp.with(context)
                .load(rowItem.FlagUrl)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .override(imageSize)
                .into(imageView)


        return rowview
    }

    override fun getDropDownView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        return getView(position, convertView, parent)
    }

}
```

flag_spinner.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/flag_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    tools:src="@drawable/ic_flag">

</ImageView>
```

The part in SignInActivity.kt

```
val adapter = CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.flag_spinner, it)
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
        flag_spinner.adapter = adapter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can't easily set the dropdown height, I believe it isn't being displayed correctly because the image is not loaded the first time you open it.

Try to change your `ImageView` size from `wrap_content` to a fixed width and height. For example:

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/flag_image"
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    tools:src="@drawable/ic_flag"/>
```